# ETL lookup transformation equivalent in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am evaluating Apache Nifi for moving data to Hive from Postgresql database. While moving the data to Hive, I am having a requirement to mask/transform some of the data attributes using a lookup table similar to what can be done using lookup transformations available in ETL tools. What options are available to achieve the same in Apache Nifi ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`ReplaceText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) and [`ReplaceTextWithMapping`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceTextWithMapping/index.html) processors. In addition, there are [`EncryptContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EncryptContent/index.html), [`HashAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashAttribute/index.html), and [`HashContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashContent/index.html) processors available to perform standard cryptographic operations on the data.

Comment: Not really looking for encryption or hashing. I will check out replaceTextWithMapping. Thanks